# Apollo GraphQL: use case for merge function in type policy?

Tags: javascript, caching, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I previously asked this question on [Apollo’s community chat](https://spectrum.chat/apollo/apollo-client/use-case-for-merge-function-in-type-policy%7E05fa4e19-9319-480e-a349-41faa94a2773), but am reposting it here because it wasn’t answered after two weeks.

This question is about the new cache introduced by [Apollo 3.0](https://www.apollographql.com/blog/announcing-the-release-of-apollo-client-3-0/). This update deprecated local queries in favour of “type policies” (or “field policies”), which include several tools for working with the cache, such as a `merge` function that can be defined for each GraphQL type to specify how incoming data should be merged with existing data in the cache.

I’m wondering which use cases are better suited for the `merge` function, versus writing a precalculated update value via `writeQuery` or `writeFragment`.

Let’s say I have an array with objects, and this array is property of another type. For example:

```
type Person {
  hobbies: [Hobby!]!
}
```

The application allows me to delete, add, and update elements in this array. Should `hobbies` make use of the `merge` function? Previously, I wrote this logic in local mutation resolvers, but these have been deprecated. I can easily mimic the old behaviour by defining a function for each of these resolvers, which contains the add/remove/update logic, and uses `writeFragment` to store the results.

I can see the benefit of using `merge` because (I think) it’s a lower layer of abstraction, but can it be used in the case of incoming `hobbies` array? As far as I can see, the way it would work would imply that we’d have to deduce the type of mutation by means of the incoming input. For example:

- If the incoming array contains one less item (or only contains the deleted item), we did a delete operation, and we can assume that all other elements remained the same.
- If the incoming array contains just one element and it is new, we did an add operation, and will merge this one element inside the array
- If the incoming array contains the same number of elements (or has just one updated item), we must have updated one and must now figure out which one to replace (let’s assume that, due to the implementation, it is not possible to directly update a single `Hobby`, because other hobbies may be affected as well, e.g. due to non-overlapping time constraints).

This seems less elegant than mirroring the old approach where the new value for `hobbies` is calculated before calling `writeFragment`.

Is there a performance benefit to using `merge`? Are existing and non-affected items in `hobbies` kept in place when using `merge`, and overwritten when using `writeFragment`? Assuming the newly calculated data passed to `writeFragment` contains an array with shallow copies for the unmodified elements.

Thank you very much for clearing this up for me!

Comment: I am wondering the same thing. When does `merge` result in simpler code than a read/writeQuery after each mutation? If you have mutations that add/remove a single item and others that overwrite the entire set, then you need some merge magic to handle all that. Isn't it better to keep doing manual read/writes so your cache update logic is next to the mutations doing the changes? The only use-case I see for `merge` is pagination, but docs/console warnings seem to push it for everything (although v3.4 made cache writes default to overwriting again).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime, I implemented a merge function similar to what’s outlined in the [Apollo docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-field-behavior/#merging-arrays-of-non-normalized-objects). This function reuses as many items from the `existing` array as possible, and takes an item from `incoming` otherwise. Equality is checked based on object `id`, which is pretty much always present in my app.

The only (minor) downside to this approach seems to be that it doesn’t handle the case where items in an array are being changed, but such manipulations are done in separate mutations that don’t return an array, anyway.

For the sake of posterity, my implementation is as follows:

```
import type { FieldPolicy, Reference } from '@apollo/client'

/**
 * Based on example in Apollo docs
 *
 * @see https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-field-behavior/#merging-arrays-of-non-normalized-objects
 */
export const mergeArrayByIdFieldPolicy: FieldPolicy<Reference[]> = {
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/default-param-last
  merge: (existing = [], incoming = [], { readField, mergeObjects }) => {
    const merged = [...incoming]
    const existingIds = existing.map((item) => readField<UUID>('id', item))

    merged.forEach((item, index) => {
      const itemId = readField<UUID>('id', item)
      const existingIndex = existingIds.findIndex((id) => id === itemId)
      if (existingIndex !== -1) {
        merged[index] = mergeObjects(existing[existingIndex], merged[index])
      }
    })
    return merged
  },
}
```

Comment: I had a similar issue today where we had a simple merge with just [...existing, ...incoming], but some mutations add or remove a single item from the list, and using the useMutation.update method to update the cache with readQuery/writeQuery, it would duplicate all the items in the list. So I made a check in the 3rd argument of merge, `options`, for the variables. If it includes a pagination variable like `cursor` or `nextPage` I concat like above, otherwise I return the incoming.